# Kernel panic seems to be unrelated to the changes

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, panic

I made changes in sched.c in Linux kernel 2.4 (homework), and now the system goes into kernel panic. The strange thing is: it seems to pass A LOT of booting checks and initializations, and panics only at the very end, showing hte following stack trace:

```
update_process_times
do_timer
timer_interrupt
handle_IRQ_event
do_IRQ
call_do_IRQ
do)wp_page
handle_mm_fault
do_page_fault
do_sigaction
sys_rt_sigaction
do_page_fault
error_code
```

And the error is: "In interrupt handler - not synching"

I know it's hard to tell without any code, but can anybody make an educated guess to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Not without code, or at least a minimal description of what your chaneges are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you my own personal mantra when debugging kernel problems: "it's always your fault."

I often see issues due to overwriting memory outside where I'm working -- if I feed hardware an incorrect address for DMA for example.  You may be screwing up a lock somehow; that seems possible in this case if you are seeing a timeout: a forgotten locked lock is causing a timeout to occur due to a hang.

To me, a panic in update_process_times might suggest a problem with the task struct pointer... but I really have no idea.

Keep in mind that things in the kernel often go wrong long before a failure occurs, so a wrong bit anywhere in your code may be to blame, even if it doesn't seem like it should have an effect.  If you can, I recommend incrementally adding or removing your code and checking for the problem to see if you can isolate it.

Comment: It looks like we accidentally deleted something in sched.h
We reinserted the changes into a fresh version and now it works. 
Thanks for the advice, and now I'd like to vote this thread closed. It seems too unfocused to be of any help to anybody.